# how to implement localstorage to detect app's first run after installation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been searching about how to detect an app's first run in ionic and i'm trying to follow the local storage example here:

[First Run after app installation](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/first-run-after-app-installation/30204/6)

I added this code to the app.js run function:

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $state, Application) {

    var state = "mainPage";  // whatever, the main page of your app

    if (Application.isInitialRun()) {
        Application.setInitialRun(false);
        state = "intro";
    }

    $state.go(state);

});
```

However, my app is showing a blank white screen once run.

How do i implement local storage to detect the app's first run? am i missing something?

Comment: Why don't you write a code that checks for a specific variable in local storage? 1)If it is not there then it is the first time your app is running. Then create that variable in local storage. 2) If it is there, then the app has ran before and it should proceed with the 'not the first time' scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller which loads first i.e your `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('\firstPage')`

```
if(localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
    localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
    $state.go('onetime.view'); 
}
else{
    $state.go('your.route');
}
```

So when your app loads first time, Your localstorage will be null. So it will route you to your first time page and also set the localstorage, So that when you load the app second time the condition will not be satisfied.